# Elaborated type refers to a typedef QBChatDialogType

Tags: ios, quickblox

> **Edit:** As suggested in comments by @Pichirichi removing enum helped

I have a Quickblox application that used SDK version 2.1. I tried updating it by using SDK version 2.6 but I recieve an error in the Header file in the framework.

The file is `QBChatDialog.h` and error reads as:

> Elaborate type refers to a typedef

at the following line.

```
- (QB_NONNULL instancetype)initWithDialogID:(QB_NULLABLE NSString *)dialogID type:(enum QBChatDialogType)type;
```

I checked all the process again but everything is done as specified in documentation.

What could be the reason for the error. Any pointers to the solution will be helpful.

Please see the screenshot: [image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use?
can you share a screenshot with the warning?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko please see the screenshot. I am using Xcode 7.1

Comment: Any updates? I got the same issue.

I used only Quickblox 2.6.6 and it worked just fine. 
As soon as I added Quickblox-WebRTC, 2.2 and it gave the same error. 
Used XCode 7.2.1. Installed both using Cocopods if that helps.

Comment: Just remove the "enum" from the function definition.